# HIV-RT nucleotide contact residues

Tags: hiv, reverse-transcription

I'm investigating HIV-RT 3KLF and 1LWF trying to find a perfect pose of thymine. Which residues on HIV-RT is Thymine supposed to contact on 3KLF and 1LWF? Where exactly is the nucleotide binding domain on 3KLF and 1LWF?

Please provide a journal article as proof.

Answer (score 2):

Thymine must make contact in two places on HIV-RT before being added to nucleotide strand. First contact is made with the fingers region then contact is made at the N-Site. 
[Allosteric Regulation of HIV-1 Reverse Transcriptase by ATP for Nucleotide Selection](http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0008867)

[image: Finger and N-Site]